# Image Link is perfect in inspect element but when opened in new tab "/" disappears

Tags: php, mysql, html, image, google-chrome

I am facing a serious issue in my website. 
Image link what I see when I inspect is for some categories : https://www.waggster.com/media/com_jomclassifieds/items/334/westpawbeds.jpg 
Which seems to be perfectly fine.

But still, chrome is unable to show the image. When I copied the link from inspect element and tried to view the image in new tab, https://www.waggster.commedia/com_jomclassifieds/items/334/westpawbeds.jpg the "/" after .com is removed automatically.

The website runs fine in another browser eg: Mozilla . Please help me to sort this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Demo link : http://ssprojects.asia/waggster/final

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe your clipboard is somehow broken?